# Qual lógica utilizar para escrever este programa em C?

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, stack, fila

Estou resolvendo uma lista de exercícios sobre pilhas e filas e travei em uma questão onde pede para escrever o programa de acordo com pseudo código da questão.

Tenho pouca experiência com C, então, não estou conseguindo resolver essa questão.
Queria a ajuda de vocês do SO para criar esse programa.

**Programa:**

```
Programa inverte var P : Pilha;

n : inteiro;

s : literal;

Início

Imprima('Entre com uma frase: ');

Leia(s)

Inicia(P); //{Torna a pilha vazia}

Para n de 1 até COMP(s) faça

PUSH(P, s[n]);

Enquanto não Vazia(P) faça //{pilha vazia, para}

Imprima (POP(P));

Fim-enquanto;

Fim
```

Comment: E qual sua dúvida? Até onde chegou? Nos motre seu código atual para que possamos ajudá-lo a resolver seu problema, e não fazer seu exercício.

Answer (score 4):

Boa tarde Leonardo,

Primeiramente vamos quebrar o problema em pequenas partes:

- **O que seu programa deve fazer?**

Pelo título posto, "inverte", é fácil deduzir que ele quer inverter uma *string* usando uma estrutura de pilhas, onde o usuário vai digitar uma palavra/frase e a mesma deve ser impressa invertida ao final da execução.

- **Mas a final, como posso fazer isso utilizando pilhas?**

Pilhas são estruturas de dados do tipo *LIFO [Last in, First out]*, ou seja, o último elemento a entrar deve ser o primeiro a sair.

Ilustração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A partir disso podemos deduzir que, para inverter sua *string* usando uma pilha, basta empilhar e desempilhar em seguida.

- **Dicas para a implementação:**

Já que você não tem muita experiência com `C`, eu fortemente sugiro que você estude a aplicação do `malloc`, `do...while()` e, principalmente, ponteiros.

Tradução de comandos do seu pseudo código:

Imprima = `printf();`
Leia = `scanf();`
Enquanto = `while();`
Para = `for(;;);` [Laço de repetição, assim como o while]

Espero ter ajudado, abraços e bons estudos!